# Best way to check against predefined values

Tags: javascript, cypress

This is a calendar check. For example: 100 days of history is available but 101 days back would be disabled for certain market.

Code is following:

```js
const todaysDate3 = dayjs().subtract(101, 'days').format('DD')
const todaysDate4 = dayjs().subtract(100, 'days').format('DD') //etc
 cy.visit(`http://calendar.whatever/ICN&markettype=ICN`);
cy.get('.calendar-table').click
cy.get('.calendar-table').contains('td',(todaysDate3)).should("have.class","disabled")           
cy.get('.calendar-table').contains('td',(todaysDate4)).should("have.class","enabled")
```

What would be the best practice to make such test for 80, 100, 365 etc days as every market. Worst case scenario I can think of is something like

```js
export const 100days = [{
  "url": (`http://calendar.whatever/ICN`),
  "has100days": true
}]
```

and like this for every possible value and using
 `if (curr.has100days) //do something } else if (curr.has365days){do something else}`

Probably best would be to write some kind of function?

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you visit each market, the data-driven approach you indicate is best.

```js
const history = [
  { market: 'ICN', days: 100 },
  { market: 'ZYX', days: 120 },
  ...
]

history.forEach(data => {
  
  cy.log(`Testing ${data.market} with ${data.days} history`)

  cy.visit(`http://calendar.whatever/ICN&markettype=${data.market}`)

  const outsideHistory = dayjs().subtract(data.days+1, 'days')
    .format('D')  // no leading '0'

  const insideHistory = dayjs().subtract(data.days, 'days')
    .format('D')  // no leading '0'

  const outsideHistoryRegex = new RegExp(`^${outsideHistory}`)  // ^ = startsWith
  const insideHistoryRegex = new RegExp(`^${insideHistory}`) 

  cy.get('.calendar-table').click

  cy.get('.calendar-table').contains('td', outsideHistoryRegex)
    .last()
    .should("have.class","disabled")            

  cy.get('.calendar-table').contains('td', insideHistoryRegex)
    .last()
    .should("have.class","enabled")
}
```

I'm assuming you only want to check the history boundary for each market, but if you want to check multiple dates per market

```js
const history = [
  { market: 'ICN', days: 85 },
  { market: 'ICN', days: 100 },
  { market: 'ICN', days: 365 },
  { market: 'ZYX', days: 120 },
  ...
]

// Same function...
```

Comment: This solution is almost perfect. Having 2 issues with it. 

1.
As the calendar has 6 weeks visible (like windows calendar). It takes the first one it sees. For example: Get 28th march, gets 28 Feb as it's first in the calendar. Seems to be bad design for automation as there's always edge cases.
Can't use ".eq" also as every month is different.

2.
"contains" also gets wrong dates. For example: If the date is 8, it finds 28th from last month as that has 8 in it as well I'm guessing.

Only solution I see is to make calendar 4 weeks or to add cypress-data tag to the dates?

Comment: Problem #2 can be fixed with regex for exact text match. Problem #3 is `.format('DD')` returns `08` but using `.format('D')` corrects that. Problem #2 depends on how the 6 weeks show relative to today. I suspect `.last()` will fix it, since you deal with "history" surmise the last week showing is the one you want. Otherwise, there must be something on the calendar that tells the user which week they are looking at - add that selector into the mix.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
cy.get('.calendar-table')
  .find('td')
  .then(($ele) => {
    if ($ele.text().includes(todaysDate3)) {
      cy.wrap($ele).should('have.class', 'disabled')
      //Do Something
    } else if ($ele.text().includes(todaysDate4)) {
      cy.wrap($ele).should('have.class', 'enabled')
      //Do Something
    } else {
      //Do something
    }
  })
```